# Are dynamic frequency transmitters common? What's the terminology to use when searching for one?

Tags: terminology

Newbie question, moderately educated on RF but only the signal, not at all about the hardware. Looking to start experimenting on a concept that would require a dynamic shift over time from one frequency to another between the transmitter and receiver. When a part is listed as, for example, a 443Mhz transmitter, is that typically the only frequency it can output at? If so, what key word would I search for on a part site to find a dynamic frequency transmitter?

I tried searching "dynamic frequency transmitter" on distributor sites such as Mouser Electronics with no apparent luck in the results.

Comment: Do you mean a transmitter that can smoothly slide it's carrier frequency from frequency A to frequency B over time? I'm not sure that I know of a name for such a thing, but while it has nothing to do with the name of the beast, the phrase "regulatory hurdle" does come to mind.

Comment: @TimWescott yeah, smoothly

Comment: No it is not common, AFAIK.  Yes, it could be done, although you may need to do it yourself.  Chances are a software-defined radio could be smoothly tuned in the manner you describe -- although it's even-steven that someone may have done something to cause it to hiccough every time you change frequency.